# C programming printf, scanf

Tags: c, floating-point, include, printf, scanf

Hi i have written this code, but the output gets like :

> How many Miles have u traveled?: (number of times that u display)
>   How many gallons of gasoline have u consumed?:

and then it just skips the scanningf and    moves on to the next spot,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <float.h>

int main ()
{

    float mile;
    float gallon;

    printf("How many Miles have u traveled?: ");
    scanf("%.1f",&mile);
    printf("How many gallons of gasoline have u consumed?: ");
    scanf("%.1f",&gallon);

}
```

Comment: btw no need of float.h and string.h

Answer (score 2):

You should not format the input. So just use `%f` as a first argument of `scanf`

```
int main ()
{

    float mile;
    float gallon;

    printf("How many Miles have u traveled?: ");
    scanf("%f",&mile);
    printf("How many gallons of gasoline have u consumed?: ");
    scanf("%f",&gallon);

}
```